# Another client to replace sqlplus for access to oracle?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have some issues with how sqlplus output is formatted for the terminal and I am just thinking of writing a script around sqlplus and fixing these.

On the other hand, wow that seems really lame. Because Oracle has several tons of tools written. Yet it seems difficult to get what I want. Does anyone have another suggestion?

First, I want smarter column widths. If I create a table with a column whose max size is 200 characters but then I put "abc", "xyz" and "123" in it, do I need a 200-space wide column on the terminal to display the contents? I do not think so. I think I need 3 characters plus a couple for padding. Yet Oracle insists on giving me a 200-character wide column. Unless there is somewhere to fix this.

Second, I want easy access to a sideways display of the columns, like using \G at the end of the command in MySQL. I know there is a way to do this in Oracle but it seemed complicated. Why could there not just be a simple switch? Like a \G at the end of the command? There can be if I wrap the output to sqlplus and do this myself.

So, the question seems to be this. Should I write a simple script around sqlplus to give me what I want, or is there a way to get Oracle to give me this behavior In sqlplus? And if there is, how much extra information will I have to stuff into my head to make this work? Because it does not seem as though it should be very complicated. But Oracle is certainly not making it easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I suggest you look over the [SQL*plus reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#i1081008) - you might find some useful tips there like adjusting a column width

```
COL column_name for a20
```

you can set up your own settings in the GLOGIN file. over time, like any other CMD, you'll get your preferences just right.

To describe a table you can use `DESC`. if you want more data write your own script and reuse it with `@`.

If all this doesn't work for you, you can always switch to a GUI like Toad or SQL developer.

**EDIT:**

I'm adding one of my own scripts to show you some tricks on how to make SQL*Plus more friendly on the command line. This one is for getting segment sizes.

```
/* This is the trick - clears &1 and &2 if received an empty string */
set ver off feed off
col 1 new_v 1
col 2 new_v 2
select 1,2 from dual where 1=0;

variable p_owner varchar2(30)
variable p_segment varchar2(30)

/* set bind variables */
begin
    :p_owner := '&1';
    :p_segment := '&2';
end;
/

set feed 1

break on segment_type skip 1

column MB for a25

select  
    segment_type, 
    decode(gi_segment_name + gi_segment_type + gi_tablespace_name , 3 ,'...Grand Total', segment_name) SEGMENT_NAME,
    to_char(round(MB,3),'99,999,999.99') MB , 
    nvl(tablespace_name,'-*-') tablespace_name
from (
    select   tablespace_name , segment_type , segment_name , sum(bytes/1024/1024) MB ,
             grouping_id(segment_name) gi_segment_name ,
             grouping_id(segment_type) gi_segment_type , 
             grouping_id(segment_type) gi_tablespace_name
    from     dba_segments
    where    ((:p_owner is null and owner = user) or owner like upper(:p_owner))
    and      (:p_segment is null or segment_name like upper('%'||:p_segment||'%'))
    group by rollup(tablespace_name, segment_type , segment_name)
    )
where not (gi_segment_name = 1 and gi_segment_type = 0  and gi_tablespace_name = 0)
order by decode(segment_type,'TABLE','0','TABLE PARTITION','1','INDEX','2','INDEX PARTITION','3',segment_type) , 
        (case when segment_name like '.%' then 'z' else 'a' end) ,
        gi_segment_name ,
        MB desc , 
        segment_name;

clear break

/* clear definition for &1 and &2 after being used. 
   allows the variable to be null the next run. */
undefine 1
undefine 2
```

I'll walk you through some of the things iv'e done here

- The script accepts two parameters. The first 4 lines clears the
  parameter if none received. if you don't do this SQL*Plus will prompt
  you for them. And we dont want that.
- Setting the binds was more of a big deal in past version. It's
  intended to save Hard / Soft parse. latest version solve this
  problem. It's still a best practice though.
- The `break` is a nice touch. You'll see it.
- The grouping Id show me the sub totals on several levels.
- I've added two parameter, owner and segment name. both can contain
  wild card. both can be null. If non provided the query will fetch the
  current user segments.
- Order by decode enabled me to set a custom sort order for different
  segment types. You can change it as you wish.

I'm executing the script like this 
my segments :

```
@seg
```

Scott's segments

```
@seg scott
```

Scott's Emp related segments

```
@seg scott emp
```

I have similar scripts for session, longops, wait events, tables, constraints, locks, kill session etc .... during my daily routine i rarely write SQL for querying this stuff any more.

Comment: I wish I could use Toad or something else. Unfortunately, the db is behind a firewall and I have to telnet in. And no, we do not want to set up ssh port forwarding, though we wish we could.